# Implementation of Private Route with Auth using react-router and Context API

Tags: authentication, react.js, jsx, url-routing

I'm trying to implement safe routes and checking if the user is authorized using only Context API.

I'm also trying to avoid that the user can see a `PrivateRoute`, but I'm not sure if I coverred all edge cases.

Also, is there a better way of doing this? Better implemantation or aproach to this?

I just don't want to use `Redux` or external libraries.

I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/EduVencovsky/f8f6c275f42f7352571c92a59309e31d) but I'm also adding the full code here.

## Auth.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { checkIsAuthenticated, authSignUp, authLogin, authLogout } from '../../services/auth'

export const AuthContext = React.createContext({})

export default function Auth({ children }) {

    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        checkAuth()
    }, [])

    const checkAuth = () => checkIsAuthenticated()
        .then(() => setIsAuthenticated(true))
        .catch(() => setIsAuthenticated(false))
        .then(() => setIsLoading(false))

    const login = credentials => authLogin(credentials)
        .then(setIsAuthenticated(true))
        .catch(error => {
            alert(error)
            setIsAuthenticated(false)
        })

    const logout = () => {
        authLogout()
        setIsAuthenticated(false)
    }

    const signUp = credentials => authSignUp(credentials)
        .then(setIsAuthenticated(true))
        .catch(error => {
            alert(error)
            setIsAuthenticated(false)
        })

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, isLoading, login, logout, signUp }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

Auth.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.func,
        PropTypes.array
    ])
}
```

## PrivateRoute.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { AuthContext } from '../Auth/Auth'
import Loading from '../../views/Loading/Loading'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...otherProps }) => {

    const { isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useContext(AuthContext)

    return (
        <Route
            {...otherProps}
            render={props => (
                !isLoading
                    ?
                    (
                        isAuthenticated
                            ?
                            <Component {...props} />
                            :
                            <Redirect to={otherProps.redirectTo ? otherProps.redirectTo : '/signin'} />
                    )
                    :
                    <Loading />
            )}
        />
    )

}

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
    component: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

## example.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute'
import Auth from './components/Auth/Auth'


import Header from './components/Header/Header'
import HomePage from './views/HomePage/HomePage'
import SignUp from './views/SignUp/SignUp'
import SignIn from './views/SignIn/SignIn'
import FormList from './views/FormList/FormList'
import PageNotFound from './views/PageNotFound/PageNotFound'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Auth>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                    <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/forms" component={FormList} />
                    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </Auth>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: While there are bound to be more promising places to seek useful feedback on security implications, you are welcome to post your code here at Code Review to seek improvement when you are ready for feedback and criticism on [any aspect of the code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Here is the right place to ask about `Potential security issues`, so my post is correct?

Comment: Basically, you are reducing your change of a good review by suggesting you're only interested in security. That's what graybeard is kindly warning you for. Less relevant: I was wondering about the optimistic `100% Secure implementation` in the title. One thing I have learned is that nothing is ever a 100% secure. The moment you start thinking that, the percentage has already dropped markedly.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for your comment, now I understand much better, thanks for the advice!